# Bootstrap toggle button still working after giving ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" ng-model="isResource" ng-disabled="Subcomponent.length||resource.length"/>Yes
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-default" ng-click="subComponentYes($event,0)" ng-class="{active : isResource === false}" ng-disabled="Subcomponent.length||resource.length">
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="0" ng-model="isResource" ng-disabled="Subcomponent.length||resource.length"/>No
 </label>
</div>
```

I have added 'ng-disabled', but it's just showing that it's disabled. Clickable and other funcions are working fine.

Comment: Please share some relevant code of your controller

Comment: Add `{{Subcomponent.length||resource.length}}` to your view page to see the expression result. Are you sure it's as you expect?

Comment: if the expression is wrong then it wont even disable partially,but it is

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value of `ng-disabled` is being set in the browser. You can do this by using inspect element in browser. If the value is not `true` or `false` then you are using incorrect expression for setting the value.

Comment: the value of ng-disabled is coming in the browser.

Comment: no i am not using modal,its a simple toggle bootstrap button.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. I have been facing the same issues since the last few days. I created a css class and added to `ng-click` to disable the button.

Comment: u have to use ng-class, make a separate class and give all the style u need and give pointer event none. its working for me ,u can use pointer event none without ng-class also..

Comment: @DhirajSharma Can't we use ng-disabled directly?

Comment: i hv used ng-disabled but its giving the same issue ,its nt working.